# Is there a "quote words" operator in R?

Tags: r, quotes

Is there a "quote words" operator in R, analogous to `qw` in Perl? `qw` is a quoting operator that allows you to create a list of quoted items without having to quote each one individually.

Here is how you would do it without `qw` (i.e. using dozens of quotation marks and commas):

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @NAM_founders = ("B97",    "CML52",  "CML69", "CML103", "CML228", "CML247",
                    "CML322", "CML333", "Hp301", "Il14H",  "Ki3",    "Ki11",
                    "M37W",   "M162W",  "Mo18W", "MS71",   "NC350",  "NC358"
                    "Oh7B",   "P39",    "Tx303", "Tzi8",
                   );

print(join(" ", @NAM_founders)); # Prints array, with elements separated by spaces
```

Here's doing the same thing, but with `qw` it is much cleaner:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @NAM_founders = qw(B97    CML52  CML69  CML103 CML228 CML247 CML277
                      CML322 CML333 Hp301  Il14H  Ki3    Ki11   Ky21
                      M37W   M162W  Mo18W  MS71   NC350  NC358  Oh43
                      Oh7B   P39    Tx303  Tzi8
                   );

print(join(" ", @NAM_founders)); # Prints array, with elements separated by spaces
```

I have searched but not found anything.

Comment: Maybe something like `stringi::stri_split_boundaries` or `stri_extract_*_words`.  But it would be nice to know exactly what `qw()` does, for those that have never used Perl

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to explain `qw` better! Edited just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `scan` and a text connection:

```
qw=function(s){scan(textConnection(s),what="")}
NAM=qw("B97      CML52    CML69    CML103    CML228   CML247  CML277
                  CML322   CML333   Hp301    Il14H     Ki3      Ki11    Ky21
                  M37W     M162W    Mo18W    MS71      NC350    NC358   Oh43
                  Oh7B     P39      Tx303    Tzi8")
```

This will always return a vector of strings even if the data in quotes is numeric:

```
> qw("1 2 3 4")
Read 4 items
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

I don't think you'll get much simpler, since space-separated bare words aren't valid syntax in R, even wrapped in curly brackets or parens. You've got to quote them.

Comment: One set of quotes is way better than dozens!

Answer (score 1):

For R, the closest thing that I can think of, or that I've found so far, is to create a single block of text and then break it up using `strsplit`, thus:

```
#!/bin/env Rscript
NAM_founders <- "B97      CML52    CML69    CML103    CML228   CML247  CML277
                 CML322   CML333   Hp301    Il14H     Ki3      Ki11    Ky21
                 M37W     M162W    Mo18W    MS71      NC350    NC358   Oh43
                 Oh7B     P39      Tx303    Tzi8"

NAM_founders <- unlist(strsplit(NAM_founders,"[ \n]+"))

print(NAM_founders)
```

Which prints

```
 [1] "B97"    "CML52"  "CML69"  "CML103" "CML228" "CML247" "CML277" "CML322"
 [9] "CML333" "Hp301"  "Il14H"  "Ki3"    "Ki11"   "Ky21"   "M37W"   "M162W"
[17] "Mo18W"  "MS71"   "NC350"  "NC358"  "Oh43"   "Oh7B"   "P39"    "Tx303"
[25] "Tzi8"
```